# show kendo tooltip only when ellipsis is active

Tags: kendo-grid, ellipsis, css, kendo-tooltip

I want to show a tooltip when the content of a kendo grid element is only partially visible. **I am not able to control the display of a tooltip on the elements of a kendo grid.**
I saw this issue has been discussed but I'm not able to find The problem, it seems to be the values of offsetWidth and scrollWidth. 
The ellipsis works as expected defining in a css

```
.k-grid td {
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    table-layout: fixed;
}
```

As I saw on this forum I use a function to detect when ellipsis, namely

```
function isEllipsisActive(e) {
     return (e.offsetWidth < e.scrollWidth);
}
```

and I call it on the mouseenter event as

```
kendoGrid.tbody.on("mouseenter", "> tr > td", function (e) {    
    var target = e.target;    
    if (isEllipsisActive(target)) {    
        return target.outerText;    
    }    
    return false;    
});
```

**The problem is that misteriously I get scrollWidth and offsetWidth equal, while I expected scrollWidth to vary according to the content of the element.**
How is this possible, and what am I doing wrong ?
Thanks for any help
best regards

Marco

Comment: Were u able to solve this? I am having the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

[Here is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20562535/customize-shape-of-kendo-tooltip/21318487#21318487) of how to show tooltip only when there is a text with ellipsis (partially visible in the cell) and don't show tooltip if there is a full text is visible or if there is no text in the cell.